# Vuejs: How can I pass a sentence with <router-link> inside it as prop?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js, directive

I'm making an answer and question page in Vue.js, where the answers are encapsulated in another component. However, when I try to do this:

```
<template>
<div>
<answer-box
      answerId="availability"
      question="Do you stil make ABC?"
      :answer="answer1" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import AnswerBox from '@/components/FAQAnswer'

export default {
  components: {
    AnswerBox,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      answer1: 'Sorry, but <strong>no</strong> &mdash; we don\'t make 
      those anymore. However, you may head to our
      <router-link to="/partners">partners</router-link>
      to check if they still have them',
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

I have tried using **computed prop which replaces `&quot;` with`"`**,
**replacing " with `&quot;` when passing the prop**, and putting these
props into a v-html directive. The sentence gets rendered, but the
router-link is rendered as regular string (no link)

*btw, I'm using vue 2.5, vscode, eslint 4.10, node 8.9.3, webpack 3.8*

Comment: Dynamic components is what you need.Check this answer https://forum.vuejs.org/t/dynamically-compile-router-link/7410/2?u=bedakb

Comment: Thank you so much [Belmin Bedak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3918577/belmin-bedak) for pointing me to that direction. It helped a lot.